# Chrome error "chrome runned out of memory"

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hey guys looking forward to do a nested loop . When opening in chrome appears "Aw, Snap! Chrome run out of memory"
There error is in the code. Im struggling a bit

```
var rentarr = [0.15, 0.12, -0.07, -0.18, 0.02]
var betarr = [0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3]

var superarr1 = function (array) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        for (var b = 0.01; b <= 1; b + 0.01) {
            arr.push(array[a] * b);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(superarr1(rentarr))
```

Comment: its a typo.. `b+0.01` can be `b+=0.01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the line `for(var  b= 0.01; b<=1; b+0.01)`. You aren't changing the value of `b`, so the inner loop will never terminate. You may have meant to use `for(var  b= 0.01; b<=1; b=b+0.01)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change here, increment section is wrong

```
for(var  b= 0.01; b<=1; b=b+0.01)
```